Getting Error when trying to access Dell redfish api via .net OData Client
I am trying to use the ODataClient lib (https://github.com/OData/odata.net/tree/main). But when I am connecting to the iDrac (Redfish) I am getting following error.
 MetadataDocumentCannotHaveMoreThanOneEntityContainer : Metadata document cannot have more than one entity container.

I have used this url https://myserver.com/redfish/v1.
When I am trying to use

/redfish/v1/odata or
/redfish/v1/$metadata
then I am getting a XmlError (Data at the root level is invalid)

Code Exmaple:
public sealed class RedFishContext : DataServiceContext
{
    public RedFishContext(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, Uri serviceRoot) : base(serviceRoot)
    {
         HttpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
         Session = CreateQuery<Session>("Session");
         Format.UseJson();
    }

    public DataServiceQuery<Session> Session { get; }


    public void AddSession(Session session)
    {
        AddObject("Session", session);
    }
}

